# Connection String times out with network name, yet works with IP

Tags: sql-server, iis, connection-string, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012

**Machine 1**

- Windows Server 2008
- SQL Server 2008

The database. Contains all the information our sites use.

---

**Machine 2**

- Windows Server 2012
- IIS 8

The webserver. Uses IIS to host two sites:

- **Production site**: (default) Has the most up-to-date UI and features
- **Backup site**: Older UI, but still using the latest data from Machine 1

---

Here's how it works:

1. User goes to one of the sites hosted on Machine 2 and enters their company information
2. Machine 1 is queried for that company's connection string.
3. The site uses the connection string to connect to the correct database on Machine 1.

The problem is that about 1/3 of the connection strings use the network name (e.g. "Data Source='Machine1';") while the other 2/3 use the IP address (e.g. "Data Source=192.168.1.200;"). When connecting via the Production site, a timeout occurs if uses a connection string with a network name. However if the same user, using the same credentials, logs in to the Backup site, everything works fine regardless of which 'Data Source' is used.

I created a simple Powershell script to test the connection from Machine 2; network names and ip addresses both work, which makes me suspect it is an IIS or web.config issue. I've gone through both extensively, and these are the only differences I've noted:

- **Different Application Pools in IIS**: However when I ran "Get-CimInstance Win32_Process" it showed both instances of w3wp.exe had been started with the same command and arguments (with the exception of different pipes)
- **Slightly different web.config**. The Backup site has an entirely self-contained web.config, while the Production on stores its connection strings is a separate file.

Been banging my head against this for several days. Very limited in the steps I can take considering this a production website and
Database. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: try the machine1.fullyqualifed.domainname.com

Comment: also try machine1 with the network protocol specified in the connection string.  see https://www.connectionstrings.com/define-sql-server-network-protocol/       ;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;

Comment: Network protocol was the problem, albeit in a different manner. For some reason the application is using Named Pipes (which are disabled on the server) instead of TCP. Going to see tomorrow if enabling Named Pipes did the trick (server config can only be reset once a day). Thank you for your help.

Comment: I added a "real" answer.  Named Pipes network-protocol was my issue back in the day.  4 days at a client site in Newark NJ trying to resolve it.  I stumbled upon it by accident, because one machine (at the entire place) worked great.  Turns out another vendor had installed an application that made tcp the default protocol on that single client machine.  Thus my 2 week adventure into how to set the protocol AND not allow another vendor to mess it up.  Thus why I prefer the connection string method.

Comment: "albeit in a different manner."  It is kind of the same problem.  Basically, its picking the wrong network-protocol.  My connection string addition was a quick way to force it to test it.  If you do the ODBC trick below, you can also set the server-to-protocol relationship in the registry.

Comment: If your issue is resolved, please either (a) mark an existing answer as "the answer" or (b) add your own answer and mark as "the answer".  This is to keep this question coming up as the filter of unanswered SOF questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the network-library in the connection string to force tcp.

see [connectionstrings.com/define-sql-server-network-protocol](http://connectionstrings.com/define-sql-server-network-protocol)

**;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;**

PS

Yep.  Been there, done that.  4 days of "on site" client visit.......and it was the protocol..  Thus how I learned to force it via the connection string.  You can also try this:

Create a (temporary) System DSN (ODBC in Control Panel) with a weird name like "peanutbutter".  There is a client connection button in there somewhere.  Force it to tcp.  Then search your registry for peanut butter and find out how the network library gets stored.

A picture is worth a thousand words.  See left side of image below.  (a random image from the old interweb)

[image: http://web.synametrics.com/resources/SQLServerExpress8.png]

Comment: This may shed a little light on it : (may be out dated, not sure)   https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/328383

Comment: Apologies for taking so long to respond. I had started on the path you showed here when my coworkers decided to just enable Named Pipes on the server. Worked like a charm, but I'm not entirely sure it won't conflict with anything long term. I'm going to bookmark this page in case we need to find a more direct solution as opposed to a workaround. Thanks again.